# Python: Keyframe points not being deleted

Tags: python

I am trying to go through keyframes and delete unnecessary intermediate ones. Here is what I've written. I do not need it to be efficient I just need it to work ASAP so that I can use my add-on for work that I need to get done.

I started with this:

```
    for fc in l.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        i = 2
        while i < len(fc.keyframe_points):
            kp1 = fc.keyframe_points[i-2]
            kp2 = fc.keyframe_points[i-1]
            kp3 = fc.keyframe_points[i]
            if kp1.co[1] == kp2.co[1] == kp3.co[1]:
                fc.keyframe_points.remove(kp2)
            i+=1
```

After that didnt work, I assumed that maybe fc wasn't the original fcurve and was isntead a copy, and so was not being properly updated. I thought that this would fix it, but it's still not working.

```
    l = bpy.data.objects[fix.attrib['name']].data
    for j in range(len(l.animation_data.action.fcurves)):
        fc = l.animation_data.action.fcurves[j]
        i = 2
        while i < len(fc.keyframe_points):
            kp1 = fc.keyframe_points[i-2]
            kp2 = fc.keyframe_points[i-1]
            kp3 = fc.keyframe_points[i]
            if kp1.co[1] == kp2.co[1] == kp3.co[1]:
                l.animation_data.action.fcurves[j].keyframe_points.remove(kp2)
            i+=1
```

Debugging tells me that it does reach into that if statement, just that AFAIK the next statement isn't doing anything. Any advice?

Comment: fc isn't a copy. Shouldn't you not increment i when you remove a point, since all the ones after it shift over one?

Comment: @scurest That's what I thoguht about fc, but it didn't works so that was my next guess.

*WRONG* I *think* incrementing is right, because I am deleting the middle one, not the latest one. *WRONG*

Nevermind. I ran through it in my head and see the issue

Comment: @scurest formatting edited comments is hard. I put the increment into an else statement and it works perfectly. I think I just had so many extraneous keyframes that I didn't realize I WAS deleting *some* of them. Thanks for the help.